# Как "Horizontal", и "Vertical" сделать для мобильных устройств? Unity 3d C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Здраствуйте, у меня есть машина которое управляется с помощью кнопок WASD. Как я могу сделать это на мобильные устройства с помощью UI кнопок?

Comment: Кнопка вверх +1, вниз -1 по оси Y. Вправо +1, влево -1 по оси Х.

Comment: [и дубликаты найдутся](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=wasd)